# PayPal IPN Failing

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I got an email from paypal saying:

```
 >Hello <>,

 >Please check your server that handles PayPal Instant Payment
 >Notifications (IPN). IPNs sent to the following URL(s) are failing:
 >
 >url--
 >
 >If you do not recognize this URL, you may be using a service provider
 >that is using IPN on your behalf. Please contact your service provider
 >with the above information. If this problem continues, IPNs may be
 >disabled for your account.
 >
 >Thank you for your prompt attention to this issue.
 >
 >
 >Thanks,
 >
 >PayPal
```

Is anyone familiar with this? We got 1 payment that made through today, it updated the database and all but still I am concern if this email will be a threat to our website.

I tested the IPN url using the IPN stimulator  and it worked fine. Should I need to change my IPN setting? Some forums are saying to turn off the IPN notifications. Should I assume that this is coming from the server refusing to accept the Paypal IPN? I'm so confused on what to do with this problem, let alone my client also knows.

I checked my site error logs but I couldn't find any new errors related to the my paypal IPN listener.

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the warning message you are receiving is showing "url--", you may want to double check:
-  the value [set up](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/) in your PayPal Profile > Instant Payment Notification
- or the value you have inserted in your integration in the variable "notify_url" (if you are using Website Payment Standard or "PAYMENTREQUEST_n_NOTIFYURL" (if you are using API).

When you receive an IPN warning message, I'd recommend to check your IPN history (in your PayPal account) to check what is the HTTP response that your server is returning to PayPal.

You can test your IPN listener [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNTesting/#id089BD0L50PF)
Find IPN overview [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/)